# FormGroup -> implicity change type of value

Tags: angular, typescript

i have FormControl contains int value (0 or 1) from DB and it connects to input type checkbox.

When i send the FormControl value to DB it changed to varchar 'true' and 'false'.

Can i set implicity FormControl type to be number?
Thanks!

Comment: booolean values has a boolean type why did you use varchar?

Comment: i write to DB using webAPI and i convert the FormControl.value to JObject and it automaticlly convert to 'false' and 'true'

Comment: then change the converted value back.

Comment: That's what i did and its work fine, but i'm looking for 'build-in' solution (of course - only if there is)

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: 'build-id solution' i mean: a property that set the FormControl type or something like that...

Comment: it's not a built-in solution it's home-made solution.